# How do I cache a swf file in Firefox without executing it?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, firefox

I'm attempting to bring a swf file down to Firefox to cache but not actually execute.  The swf comes from a different domain.

The following approach works in Chrome but not Firefox:

`new Image().src = "www.other.com/foo.swf";`

Firefox uses a separate cache for images.

This approach works in IE, but not Firefox:

`<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" data="www.other.com/foo.swf"   declare="1"></object>`

The "declare" tells the browser to cache but not execute it.  However, Firefox complains that the request is cross-domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an [object/embed parameter](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) that tells Flash to do nothing, and hide the object from display?

Comment: @Steve-o: are you referring to play=false?

Comment: Either that or modify the Actionscript to handle a new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a javascript solution, but you can load a Flash movie inside another Flash movie by URL, so you could fetch it that way. However, I'm not sure what the cache mechanism for that is, I don't know if Flash would do a new fetch on every page load, see http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html

Edit, see also: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/preload-and-cache-flash-flv-files.html